# Linux as a router to forward

Tags: linux, networking, nat, router, openstack

How to make an OpenStack instance to forward route to another Linux machine which is not OpenStack instance but in the same LAN?

```
PC_A has 192.168.1.133/27.
PC_B has 192.168.1.140/27.

PC_A has 10.26.14.16/25 route. 
PC_B has no 10.26.14.16/25 route.
```

I want PC_B to reach `10.26.14.16/25` via PC_A.

Note: PC_B is an OpenStack Instance. It's private IP is 192.168.118.10/27 and public IP is 192.168.1.140/27.

```
  FW----------PC_A--------------PC_B    
      [192.168.1.133/27]    [192.168.1.140/27]  Public  IP of B
                            [192.168.118.10/27] Private IP of B
```

PC_A has `10.26.14.16/25` route. PC_B has no `10.26.14.16/25` route. I want PC_B to reach `10.26.14.16/25` via PC_A.

Comment: smells like school work ... please ask a question

Comment: If you want a ready solution, there are plenty on the internet. If you have a specific question or problem, ask.

Comment: Easy: add the missing route

Comment: @rinto I converted two Answers into edits of your question; updates to your question should be edited in to it,  it posted as answers. Please review your post to make sure it looks the way you want it. Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller there's a 3rd answer left but I wouldn't know how to classify it

Comment: Ditto; it appears to include commands that might solve the problem, but I'll leave that up for others to review/comment on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks easy but it's not. Believe me!

**Server Side Configuration [PC_A]**

```
[PC_A ~]# nano /etc/sysctl.conf 
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1


[PC_A ~]# iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.1.127/27 -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
```

**Client Side Configuration [PC_B]**

PC_B is an instance of Openstack.  It's private IP is `192.168.118.10/27` and public IP is `192.168.1.140/27`.

Problem:

```
[PC_B ~]$ sudo route add default gw 192.168.1.133 eth0

SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable


[PC_B ~]$ route

default         host-192-168-10 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0

192.168.118.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth0
```

Why `SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable`?  As I already mentioned
public ip of PC_B is `192.168.1.140/27` [OpenStack Instance] and its private ip is `192.168.118.10/27`.

Answer (score 0):

If PC_B does not have direct access to the 192.168.1.* network, then the missing route needs to be added to OpenStack network settings, not into PC_B as such.